# How can I calculate the current of a simple voltage source supposing that the current changes linearly in time period t?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, batteries, current

I have a problem from my work. I am facing a problem in modelling a battery based on a voltage source model with a constant resistance:

[image]

The purpose of the calculation is to find a suitable parameter for the current by giving an energy \$Delta E\$, a time period \$t_{op}\$ and a maximal output power \$p_{max}(t_{op})\$ in the discharge mode.

Suppose that the current of the battery output changes linearly within the time \$t \in [0, $t_{op}]\$. The equation of the power output can be written as \$P = VI - I^2 R\$, where \$I = at + b\$. If we conduct the equation further, we can find that the power output is equal to:

\$P = - Rt^2a^2 + tVa - 2tRab - Rb^2 + Vb\$ with only two variables {a,b} (other values are already known in the calculation)

If we integrate the power output from time 0 to time \$t_{op}\$, the output energy will be:

\$Delta E = - 1/3R(t_{op})^3a^2 + 1/2(t_{op})^2Va - (t_{op})^2Rab - R(t_{op})b^2 + V(t_{op})*b\$

If the maximal output power is given as \$P_{max}\$ in time period \$t_{op}\$, the second equation can be built as: \$P_{max} = - R*(t_{op})^2a + (t_{op})Va - 2(t_{op})Rab - Rb^2 + V*b\$

Therefore, we get a quadratic equation group with two variables.

Solve[

\$Delta E = - 1/3R(t_{op})^3a^2 + 1/2(t_{op})^2Va - (t_{op})^2Rab - R(t_{op})b^2 + V(t_{op})*b\$

\$P_{max} = - R*(t_{op})^2a + (t_{op})Va - 2(t_{op})Rab - Rb^2 + V*b\$

] for {a,b}

How can I simplify this equation group due to its complexity?

I have tried to solve this problem with matrix representation of conic sections.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections

This matrix method will deliver me four possible solutions by solving a cubic matrix equation problem.

I was surprised by the mathematical complexity in such a simple electrical circuit problem. I think I have missed something important in the modelling, which makes the problem too complex.

Comment: I think you need to provide much more context to the paragraph beginning: *The purpose of the calculation is to find a suitable parameter for the current....*

Comment: I would also consider the load in the calculations. Furthermore, KVL must be respected.